# How to style views' pager in drupal?

Tags: drupal-6

I need to style pager provided by views in my own way. like it should show page numbers like "1 2 3 4 5..." instead the original one provided by views having "first" "last" etc.
How can i style the pager in this way?

Thanks

Comment: For others with similar questions regarding theming or styling a views pager. This might help http://codekarate.com/blog/drupal-6-override-views-pager-theme-function

Answer (score 3):

See [this page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--pager.inc/function/theme_pager/6#comment-693) regarding theme_pager for Drupal.  Other people show how to custom theme the pager for your site.